# MIPS Basic For Loop

Tags: assembly, mips

im trying to implement this java code into MIPS assembly language and i am quite confused. this is what i have so far:

java code:

```
          for (int c = 1; c <= rows; c++) {
              number = highestValue; // reset number to the highest value from previous line

              for (i = 0; i < c; i++) {
                  System.out.print(++number + " ");
              }

              highestValue = number; // setting the highest value in line
```

assembly code:

```
.text    # tells the program where the code begins

    move $t0, $zero    # t0=0  
    move $t1, $zero    # this will be similar to "int i = 0"    
    move $t2, $zero    # this will be similar to "number = 0"  
    move $t3, $zero    # this will be similar to "highestValue = 0"
    add $t4, $zero, 1  # this is our c
    move $t5, $a1      # this is what will have our user input thru command line (rows!)

    # biggest for-loop for(int c = 1; c <= rows; c++)
    for:
    bgt $t4, $a1, exit
    move $t2, $t3

        for1:   # for(i = 0; i < c; i++)
        bgt $t1, $t4, exit1    # if c is greater than i 

        li $v0, 5 
        la $t2, printNum
        syscall 

        add $t1, $t1, $1         # increment by 1

        j for1

        exit1:

        move $t2, $t3

.data   # tells to store under .data line (similar to declaring ints)
    printNum: .ascii z "$t2"
```

Comment: so, your problem isn't java, it's assembly?

Comment: yes it is assembly!

Comment: _"and i am quite confused"_ is not a very good problem description. What exactly are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 2):

Let's follow the flow of control:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) { body }
```

---

```
int i = 0;
while ( i < n ) {
    body
    i++;
}
```

Now if we nest one for-loop inside another loop, we still have to follow this pattern.  Nesting of control structures in assembly is the same, you fully nest one control structure inside the other.  Do not intermix piece parts from nested constructs and outer constructs.  Fully *start and finish* the inner control structure before resuming the outer one.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
    for ( j = 0; j < m; j++ ) {
       body
    }
}
```

---

```
int i = 0;
while ( i < n ) {
    int j = 0;   <----- this must be here; we cannot hoist this outside of the outer loop
    while ( j < m ) {
        body
        j++;
    }
    i++;    <--------- your missing this
} <---------- and this
```